# Magento 2: Calling a cms block in default xml

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, default.xml

I am trying to call a static block in the footer block but it does not work.

I created a theme and then created a default xml:

> \app\design\frontend\MyTheme\Theme-frontend-default\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml

i then removed the default footer links:

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true"/>
```

i then added the code to the block:

```
<referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_navigation">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="footerNavigation" xsi:type="string">footer_navigation</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
  </referenceContainer>
```

I had earlier created the block programmatically using an InstallData.php :

```
$cmsBlock = $this->blockInterfaceFactory->create();
        $cmsBlock->setIdentifier('footer_navigation')
            ->setTitle(self::Footer_Navigation)
            ->setContent('{{block class="Topclick\CmsPages\Block\Cmspages" template="Topclick_CmsPages::blockTemplates\footerNavigation.phtml"}}')    
            ->setData('stores', [0]);
        $this->blockRepository->save($cmsBlock);
```

so. i am unclear why its not working. i did however test the block and it does indeed render on normal pages using this:

```
echo $this->getLayout()
          ->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')
          ->setBlockId('footer_navigation')
          ->toHtml();
```

Why my **xml** doesn't work ?

Comment: `<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('footer_navigation')->toHtml(); ?>` doesn't work after clearing cache ?

Comment: First confirm that, your block created or not?

Comment: hi @DhirenVasoya-- i did indeed test whether it was created. it is.i rendered your code and it showed up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with below code in your **\app\design\frontend\MyTheme\Theme-frontend-default\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml** file.

I have called static block id "footer-custom-links". Please change with your static block id.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">  
  <body>
    <referenceContainer name="footer-container">  
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footercustom-links" as="footercustom-links" after="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer-custom-links</argument>
            </arguments>
          </block>
    </referenceContainer>
  </body>
```

Thanks

Comment: and which one is the name="block_id". is that just a random name?

Comment: No, "block_id" means it will pass "CMS Block ID" as argument. And replace "footer-custom-links" with your actual CMS Static block ID. So, your static block will display in footer section.

Answer (score 0):

Change your xml by following code:

```
<referenceContainer name="footer">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_navigation">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">17</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: hi Sohel. i tried your code but its does not work. do you have any idea how i can go about debugging this.

Comment: This is working fine for me. Did you change your correct block_id, replace 17 to your and clear cache.

Comment: Open Magento\Cms\Block\Block, debug inside _toHtml. Don't forget to clear cache.

Comment: where would i get that block id from. also where did you get the 17 from?

Comment: When you create static block, you must have id

Comment: hi . yes. it is this one: setIdentifier('footer_navigation'). the identificer. also where did you get the number 17 from. i mean, where is my number located

Comment: Check cms_block table or Admin -> Content -> Blocks